# How to group joined tables by aggregate function, specifically by average group-name type?

Tags: oracle, join

I'm trying to build a query selecting two columns (category types) from one table JOINED to another table-column displaying average grades as percentage number-types; here is my first attempt:

```
SELECT gt.grade_type_code,
       gt.description,
       gg.numeric_grade
FROM student.grade_type gt
JOIN student.grade gg ON gt.grade_type_code = gg.GRADE_TYPE_CODE;
```

Here is a screenshot of output for clarification:

[image]

My second attempt is closer to the expected result, sans "DESCRIPTION" column, necessitating the JOIN clause; I've also included the query and output below:

```
SELECT grade_type_code,
       count(grade_type_code),
       Round(avg(numeric_grade),2)
FROM student.grade
GROUP BY grade_type_code
ORDER BY GRADE_TYPE_CODE;
```

[image]

Lastly, here is my most recent attempt to combine the above logic:

```
SELECT gt.grade_type_code,
       gt.description,
       round(avg(gg.numeric_grade),2)
FROM student.grade_type gt
JOIN student.grade gg ON gt.grade_type_code = gg.GRADE_TYPE_CODE
GROUP BY gt.grade_type_code
ORDER BY gt.grade_type_code;
```

And the error message:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 28
```

So essentially, I'm attempting to display the average NUMERIC_GRADE for the correspondingly grouped category types (i.e. Participation = avg percentage) but my `GROUP_BY` attempts invariably return errors (not sure why).  I believe my logic is directionally correct, albeit flawed; could someone please advise?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### ORA-00979 not a GROUP BY expression
>
> **Cause:** The GROUP BY clause does not contain all the expressions in the SELECT clause. SELECT expressions that are not included in a group function, such as AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, STDDEV, or VARIANCE, must be listed in the GROUP BY clause.
>   **Action:** Include in the GROUP BY clause all SELECT expressions that are not group function arguments.

`Gt.description` column is not listed in the `group by` clause. Columns not participating in group function should be listed in group by clause.

```
SELECT gt.grade_type_code,
       gt.description,
       round(avg(gg.numeric_grade),2) AS "Average Grade"
FROM student.grade_type gt
JOIN student.grade gg ON gt.grade_type_code = gg.GRADE_TYPE_CODE
GROUP BY gt.grade_type_code,
         gt.description
ORDER BY gt.grade_type_code;
```